# How can i create an extension security hash code in Google chrome Secure Preferences file

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, hash, google-chrome-extension

I was looking for adding extensions to Chrome with code. And i succeeded to do this in Chrome version 35 some how, but according to new releases of Google chrome like version 37+, there's a new json file named 'Secure Preferences' in profile folder. in this file there is some tags named protection>macs>extensions>settings which includes a hash code as value of a key for each extension ID like i put one extension to the below:

```
"protection": {
  "macs": {
     "extensions": {
        "settings": {
           "pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia": "CC15DD2467ADCD7C4226CECF827B57267AF9FB7E10E9540CBDD72A67436DB4ED"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

My question is how can i generate the hash value of this part for each exstsion ID?

i stuck only for one line in this code, please show me a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The purpose of this hash is *specifically* to prevent applications from installing extensions behind the user's back.

If you want the user to install an extension, upload the extension to the Chrome Store and provide the user with the URL to install it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i can forecast the ID of extension, what remains is the hash value of the json array, is there any way find the solution?

Comment: No. The required value will be different for every machine that your extension is installed on.

Comment: That makes Chrome a non-portable browser. Running your profile from a USB stick in another computer would reset your installed extensions.

Comment: There is a way to do it as described by https://www.adlice.com/google-chrome-secure-preferences/ but it is rather complicated I would say.